# Python: Find the values for 2 strings in a line of text

Tags: python

I have some lines with different ids that I want to find.

The text line might look like this:

"

> The first ID_1:4533 and the second is ID_0: 123"
>
> In this line the first is ID_0: 24 and the other is ID_1: 65

My goal is to find the number of the first ID (4533 in line 1 and 24 in line 2) and put those numbers in one list  and then the number of the second ID and append them in a second list.

The below code should demonstrate what I would want, but it doesn't work because the ID can be called either ID_0 or ID_1. I would ideally just search for ID_ and then return the number regardless of whether it is ID_0 or ID_1

```
ID_1 = "ID_1:([0-9]+)"
match = re.search(ID_1, line)
firstNumber = match.group(1)
secondNumber = match.group(2)
```

What I imagine is a code that would work like this instead:

```
ID = "ID_0:([0-9]+)" or  "ID_1:([0-9]+)" 
match = re.search(ID, line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `re.findall`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """The first ID_1:4533 and the second is ID_0: 123
In this line the first is ID_0: 24 and the other is ID_1: 65
"""
firstNumber = []
secondNumber = []
for line in s.splitlines():
    fNum, sNum = re.findall(r"ID_\d*:\s?(\d*)", line)
    firstNumber.append(fNum)
    secondNumber.append(sNum)

print(firstNumber)
print(secondNumber)
```

**Output:**

```
['4533', '24']
['123', '65']
```